# Virtual Environment Requirement for PIP on Mac

Tags: python, bash, virtualenv

I am running a python script on MACOSX 10.15.7(Catalina). In my Bash Profile, I have the following line:
`export PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV=false`

However, everytime I am trying to run any python script it shows the following error:
`ERROR: Could not find an activated virtualenv (required).`

I apreciate if anyone can help me to figure this problem out. I tried multiple solutions discussed in the stackoverflow but none of them worked for me.

Comment: Can you get python version on your bash?

Comment: My python version is Python 3.8.2

Comment: I remember one I had the same problem I resolved it by brew uninstall and install python. it will solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

> In my Bash Profile, I have the following line: `export PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV=false`

OK, so that is a little strange.  Because setting PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV to `false` or an empty string, or unsetting it should turn off that warning.  (I just checked.)

So I think you must be running in a context where that environment variable setting hasn't taken effect.

- Did you "source" the profile after adding that to the profile?  Or restart the shell?  Type `echo $PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV` to see what the variable is set to in the shell.
- Are you (perchance) using `sudo`?  By default, environment variable settings are NOT passed through to the environment in which `sudo` runs the command.

I also think it can't be running "any python script".  I think it must be some script that entails running `pip`.